# Obtain number of rows where one column has a value and the others don't

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 48 columns and 4000 rows. I want to know the number of rows (or in %) where one column has a value and the others are null, but for all columns (as factorial, so I can obtain all possible combinations in a row, between filled variables and NaN).

**For example:**

in 20% of total rows, varA is filled and all others are NaN

in 30% of total rows, varA and varB are filled and all the others are Nan

Can someone help me with the code in python??

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: I added a [tag:pandas] because you mentioned dataframes, but please change this if it is not accurate. Also, please provide a [mre] or at least some example of your data instead of just describing it. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953).

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import combinations

result = {
    cols: (
        df[list(cols)].notna().all(axis=1)               # the selected variables are not nan
        & df.drop(columns=list(cols)).isna().all(axis=1) # and the rest is nan
    ).sum()
    # change to combinations(df.columns, 1) for single variable
    # change to combinations(df.columns, 3) for triple variable
    # etc.
    for cols in combinations(df.columns, 2)
}
```

Result is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    ('varA', 'varB'): 10,
    ('varA', 'varC'): 20,
    ...
}
```

... which means there are 10 rows where `varA` and `varB` are filled but the remaining variables are all NaN; 20 for the `(varA, varC)` combination.

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) will give you a series of boolean values indicating whether the argument is `not-NaN`, so you have `True` for `not-NaN` and `False` for `NaN`.

You can do this for all the columns you care about, and then use [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html)
with `axis=1` to find which rows satisfy this condition for *all* columns you care about.

[`pd.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)  will give you the inverse. To enforce the "all other columns are NaN" condition, you can apply this similar treatment to the columns you are not interested in.

Finally, `.sum()` on a boolean array will give the number of elements that are `True`, which is what we want.

```
import numpy as np

def count_not_na_rows(df: pd.DataFrame, columns_with_values: list) -> int:
    nan_columns = list(set(df.columns) - set(columns_with_values))
    not_nan_rows = np.logical_and.reduce(pd.notna(df.loc[:, columns_with_values]), axis=1)
    nan_rows = np.logical_and.reduce(pd.isna(df.loc[:, nan_columns]), axis=1)
    result = np.logical_and(not_nan_rows, nan_rows)
    return result.sum()
```

To test this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 1, np.nan],
 [1, np.nan, np.nan],
 [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=["varA", "varB", "varC"])

count_not_na_rows(df, ["varA"])  # 1  -> only one row has varA but NaN for everything else
count_not_na_rows(df, ["varB"])  # 0  -> No rows have varB but NaN for everything else
count_not_na_rows(df, ["varC"])  # 0

count_not_na_rows(df, ["varA", "varB"]) # 1 -> only one row has varA and varB but NaN for everything else
```

Comment: ~thank you so much!! I can't vote, but it helped a lot!!